# How can check and validate video mime type using php?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, video

I am making a video upload module in which I have validate video by extension, Now i want to validate the video by mime type. Can anyone let me know can validate mime type?

Comment: Where do you want to do the validation, if on the PHP side then you look at `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` where 'userfile' is the name attribute value of your `<input type=file'... />` HTML Tag. BTW: Don't trust it to be correct as it is up to the OS to send you this information and depending on the OS and the way the user has their MIME mapping set, you could easily get `application/octet-stream` instead of `video/whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

her is the example to check mime type it will solve your problem.

[PHP-manual function mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: there is solution if you read it. here is no one to code for you show your effort of coding unless no one help you

Comment: Stackoverflow discourages link-only answers.  Please, at least, provide a summary of the solution.  A brief code snippet would be helpful too.